# rectangle layout with a small triangle arrow attached to its side

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an Android app and trying to create a list item view for my RecyclerView, that will look like the one in the [picture](https://ibb.co/cho4NS).

I successfully created the view (using 3 RelativeLayouts side by side inside a LinearLayout) but without the triangle arrow.

Can someone please advise on how to reach the desired result with the triangle arrow in an xml drawable?

Please note that the rectangles should have same x coordinates and only the arrow needs to "invade" to the adjacent layout area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add images with the desired color with attribute center vertical to true, you can find the icons on https://material.io/icons/

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing what you suggested instead of coding a drawable shape in xml. Just made the image align parent start/end and rotated it 180 degrees using android:rotation="180" attribute for getting a left arrow